# How to store values from ng-dropdown-multiselect in sessionStorage in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am looking for a simple way to save and load data to / from session storage when it comes to multiselect dropdown. I'm using AngularJS.

Saving and loading data happens on a page reload.

HTML:

```
<div class="select-wrapper">
       <p class="par-multiselect-title">Items to choose from: </p>
       <div ng-dropdown-multiselect="" options="items" selected-model="selectedItems" extra-settings="mySettings"></div>
</div>
```

Here is how I solved it when it comes to single text input or checkbox. I can't however crack multiselect dropdown.

```
sessionStorage.setItem("name", $('#name').val());
sessionStorage.setItem("isNew", document.getElementById("isNew").checked);

if (sessionStorage.getItem("name")) {
    $scope.itemName = sessionStorage.getItem("name");
} 

var isNewChecked = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem("isNew"));
if (isNewChecked == true) {
    document.getElementById("isNew").checked = isNewChecked;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `sessionStorage.setItem` supports string only, you can stringify the json:

```
$scope.selectedItems = [/* ... */];
sessionStorage.setItem("selectedItems", JSON.stringify($scope.selectedItems));
```

and load:

```
$scope.selectedItems = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem("selectedItems"));
```

Comment: Great. Thanks. $scope + JSON.stringify did the job.